# Creating an auto filter code

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

Good Morning,

I am considerable new to VBA and was looking for some assistance on writing an auto-filter code for my table.

```
Tariffs     |   SME100  |   Enterprise  |   CustomerLoyalty |   AccountManage   
------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------      
Voda Red    |   1       |     1         |         0         |          1
Voda 1G D   |   1       |     0         |         1         |          0

1* eligible to sell
0* not eligible sell
```

I am trying to write a code that takes the value from a validation box ("B2") and automatically filters the specific column of that sales channel for the eligible tariffs. My current code is:

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim strRange As String
    strRange = "B"
    Dim b As Integer
    b = "2"
    Range = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Address(False, False)

    If Range = True And Range = "SME100" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TariffTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1"

    If Range = True And Range = "Enterprise" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TariffTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"

    If Range = True And Range = "CustomerLoyalty" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TariffTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1"

    If Range = True And Range = "AccountManagement" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TariffTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="1"
    Else
        MsgBox ("No Sales Channel Selected")
    End If   
End Sub
```

Any advise will be much appreciated

Comment: I assume that you use excel 2013; in the object model this line could not return true or false, but the address in the language of the macro:

Range = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Address(False, False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it in a different way:

```
Sub Filter()

    Dim columnNumber, tableRow, tableColumn, tableWidth As Integer
    Dim tableName, columnName As String

    tableName = "Table1"
    columnName = ActiveSheet.range("B2").Value

    'This clears the existing filter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).range.AutoFilter

    'Assign some numbers we need to know about the table to check the headers
    tableRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).range.Row
    tableColumn = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).range.Column
    tableWidth = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).range.Columns.Count

    'If a column title with the specified value does not exist VBA throws an error which we need to catch, this is one of the many reasons I dislike VBA :D
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'Search through the table column header row to find the specified column and assign the number to columnNumber
    columnNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(columnName, range(Cells(tableRow, tableColumn), Cells(tableRow, tableColumn + tableWidth)), 0)

    'Apply the filter "1" to the found columnNumber
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).range.AutoFilter Field:=columnNumber, Criteria1:="1"

    'Exit the sub otherwise the "error handling" will be provoked
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox columnName & " does not exist"

End Sub
```

Edit: Plus you should read and understand sancho.s's answer.

Comment: Is there anyway i can extend this to show only the visible data from the table into a data validation box (which i can use as a Row Source) or alternatively make a combo box show only the visible data?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest modifications, checks, etc.:

1. You probably need `Range = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Text` (or using a different name, see below). This is likely the source of error. Plus, there is a lot to improve in your code.
2. Use `Dim colstr as String`, `colstr = ...` instead of `Range = ...`.
3. Make sure `TariffTable` is correctly defined.
4. `AccountManagement` should read `AccountManage`.
5. Make sure `ActiveSheet` refers to the `Sheet` you want to work with.
6. Inquire `If colstr = "Enterprise" Then` instead of `If colstr = True And colstr = "Enterprise" Then` (already using a changed name).
7. You can improve over using multiple `If`s, e.g., with `Select Case`, or even matching `colstr` against the `Range` containing the headings.

PS: You did not post the output/errors of your code.

Comment: He also should be using `elseif` not following directly with another `if`.